# Parcel serving on localhost not working : "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect."

Tags: javascript, localhost, parceljs

I am a beginner, i was using parcel and was working great, but suddenly it stopped serving to localhost (http://localhost:1234/) no error with building, localhost shows : "This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect".
And also i can serve with "npx serve" no problem.

```
"@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
"parcel": "^2.7.0",
"sass": "^1.26.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I believe how I fixed it was by specifying a port in the command.

`parcel index.html -p 1234`

Also it's a good idea to clear your .parcel-cache every time you restart your server, because sometimes parcel doesn't pick up the changes.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Same issue but it doesn't fix it :'(

Comment: @AntoineD I believe another thing that I tried was using the -https flag, however that does require you to have certificates set up locally. Sorry I can't be anymore help.